# Using mapshot() to save mapview(), data layer doesn't show when saving PNG

Tags: r, visualization, r-mapview

This *has* to be an easy fix but this is my first time using mapview and mapshot and I'm stuck. I've investigated other postings and the documentation but I can't see a source.

I've created an object with mapview. I can view the map ok and I can export and save successfully from the viewer. However, I'm trying to save from code using mapshot.

This works great with an html output but not for the png. No error messages show and the file saves in the right place absolutely fine. It's just that the saved PNG file shows a map and no data.

```
library(openair)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)

sites <- importMeta(source = "saqn", all = FALSE)

edinburgh_sites <- sites %>% filter(substr(site, 1, 9) == "Edinburgh")
glimpse(edinburgh_sites)
```

> Rows: 14 Columns: 5 $ site       "Edinburgh Centre", "Edinburgh Currie", "Edinbur… $ code       "ED", "ED11", "ED10", "ED5",
> "ED6", "ED2", "EDNS… $ latitude   55.95197, 55.89691, 55.93903,
> 55.93771, 55.94583… $ longitude  -3.195775, -3.319660, -3.392727, -3.232267, -3.2… $ site_type  "Urban Background", "Suburban Background", "Urba…

```
edinburgh_sites_map = mapview(edinburgh_sites, xcol = "longitude", ycol = "latitude", crs = 4326, grid = FALSE)
edinburgh_sites_map
mapshot(edinburgh_sites_map, 
        file = paste0(getwd(), "/Figures/edin_sites_map.png"))
```

In the viewer (and when exported from viewer):
[image]

When saved using mapshot() as a png:
[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly, mapshot uses webshot which uses phantomjs, right? If so I am not sure it necessarily is an easy fix, there are a lot of layers where something could be going wrong...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I still haven't managed to find a fix for this but will use the export/saving function from viewer in the interim.

Comment: @Alwayslearning I am in the middle of fixing this issue. I would appreciate if you could `remotes::install_github("r-spatial/mapview@429-update-to-webshot2")` and let me know if it fixes your issue? Please also see https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/419 for a bit more discussion around this issue.

Comment: @TimSalabim awesome, I installed the fix and it now works. Thanks for that. I'm a coding newbie so naively thought it might have been something simple in my code.

Comment: Another thing that comes to mind here is to try `mapviewOptions(fgb = FALSE)` before generating the map.

Comment: @TimSalabim I'm having the same issue and tried running that install, but it failed to download because it could not open the URL.

Comment: It has been merged into master and is now called `mapshot2()`

Comment: @TimSalabim: Has anything changed since 2022? Using data from the upper example and `{mapview}` 2.11.2, I could not create pngs using `mapshot()` (background map visible, features missing) nor `mapshot2()` (plain empty output, white only).

Answer (score 0):

Since I was facing the same issue myself and found this post, I'd like to draw a little conclusion (as of today) from the options suggested in the comments.

Basically, `mapview::mapshot()` as well as `mapview::mapshot2()` did not produce the desired result in my case, but `mapviewOptions(fgb = FALSE)` did the trick before calling `mapview()`:

```r
library(openair)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)

sites <- importMeta(source = "saqn", all = FALSE)

edinburgh_sites <- sites |> filter(substr(site, 1, 9) == "Edinburgh")

glimpse(edinburgh_sites)
#> Rows: 14
#> Columns: 6
#> $ source    <chr> "saqn", "saqn", "saqn", "saqn", "saqn", "saqn", "saqn", "saq…
#> $ site      <chr> "Edinburgh Centre", "Edinburgh Currie", "Edinburgh Glasgow R…
#> $ code      <chr> "ED", "ED11", "ED10", "ED5", "ED6", "ED2", "EDNS", "ED7", "E…
#> $ latitude  <dbl> 55.95197, 55.89691, 55.93903, 55.93771, 55.94583, 55.94427, …
#> $ longitude <dbl> -3.195775, -3.319660, -3.392727, -3.232267, -3.220556, -3.19…
#> $ site_type <chr> "Urban Background", "Suburban Background", "Urban Traffic", …
```

```r
# make rendered html self-contained
mapviewOptions(fgb = FALSE)

edinburgh_sites_map <- mapview(edinburgh_sites, 
                               xcol = "longitude", 
                               ycol = "latitude", 
                               crs = 4326,
                               grid = FALSE)

edinburgh_sites_map
```

[image]

```r
mapshot(edinburgh_sites_map, 
        file = "edin_sites_map.png")
```

[image: Mapshot Output]